# Select first text node in this markup

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to select the first *text* node in the first li in this ordered list...

```
<ol id="authors">
  <li id="CD007786-cr-0002">Robert S Phillips<sup>1,*</sup>, </li>
  <li id="CD007786-cr-0003">Shireen Gopaul<sup>2</sup>, </li><li id="CD007786-cr-0004">Faith Gibson<sup>3</sup>, </li>
```

So far I have tried:

```
jQuery("ol#authors li:first-child").text()
```

But this returns:

```
Robert S Phillips1,*,
```

What I am trying to get is simply:

```
Robert S Phillips
```

Answer (score 22):

Try

```
alert( jQuery("#authors li:first-child").contents().get(0).nodeValue );
```

Comment: how to assign a .on event for this after `.contents()` or `.get()`

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to get text nodes with regular javascript, in fact getting the correct node snould be as easy as

```
var node = document.querySelector('#authors li').firstChild;
```

To get the value

```
var text = node.nodeValue;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/709dya5a/)

Comment: this works but what if subsequent `<sup>` elements have an attribute, e.g. style, id or class? It's risky to parse HTML by hand this way.

Comment: Agree, I would love to see a solution to get the first & last `#text` nodes in any markup. I found a solution using [createTreeWalker](https://gist.github.com/erquhart/37bf2d938ab594058e0572ed17d3837a) perhaps it might helps someone.

Answer (score -2):

this will do it

```
var $first = $("#authors li:first-child").clone();
$first.find("sup").remove();
var fullName = $first.text().trim().replace(/,$/, "");
```

[click here for the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75lb/bH4ZN/)

ideally, i would change the markup structure to

```
<ol id="authors">
  <li id="CD007786-cr-0002"><span class="fullName">Robert S Phillips</span><sup>1,*</sup>, </li>
  <....>
</ol>
```

and then extract the name with

```
$("#authors li:first-child span.fullName").text();
```